# Comparing two dataframes of different lengths

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes of different lengths -

```
len(df1) = 2400
len(df2) = 100
```

df1 =>

```
colA  colB  colC
0     1     2   
3     4     5 
6     7     8  
.
.
.
2400 rows.
```

df2 (number of rows is a factor (1/24) of num_rows in df1) =>

```
colD  colE  colF
10     11     12    
13     14     15  
.
.
.
100 rows
```

Currently I get following expected error since the lengths are different , All good here. ->

comparison -

```
df1['colB'] > df2['colD']
```

Error -

```
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (2400,), (100,))
```

Requirement ->

I want to perform this comparison in a way that consecutive 24rows in df1 get compared to 1 row in df2 to get rid of this error

(row1...row24 in df1 compared with row1 in df2)

(row25..row48 in df1 compared with row2 in df2)

and so on... Is there a way to do that ?

PS - Comparison is to be done between 2 specific columns of these dfs as shown above -> colB and colD

**One way I could think of is copying the same rows 24 times in df2 and populating till 2400 rows. But I'm not sure how to do that as well since new to dataframes and numpy.**

Comment: how does the comparison of 24 rows vs 1 row look like...what do you compare exactly? do you want to compare the rows chronological (row 1-24 df1 vs. row 1 of df2, 25-48 vs. row 2 of df2 and so on)

Comment: They are numeric values as shown in the question , but random values.
(row 1-24 == row 1 of df2, 25-48 == row 2 of df2 and so on) - this is not the case.

Comment: Here’s one option. Add an index to each df. The index changes every row in df2 and every 24 rows in df1. `group_by` the index and do your comparison by group. `group_map` may be helpful. We need more information, as @Rabinzel says, to provide more specific advice.

Comment: edited the question , comparison needs to be done between two specific columns , like `df1['colB'] > df2['colD']`

Comment: @devcodes I didn't mean it the way of being equal. But for comparing data you need to have at least one distinct property in both df's. Otherwise, how do you know which rows to compare ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat your df2 24 times like this & do comparison;

```
df2_repeated = df2.loc[df2.index.repeat(24)]
df2_repeated.index = range(0,df2_repeated.shape[0])
```